# SQLAlchemy: выборка по независимому регистру букв

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

День добрый!

Предположим, есть таблица с одной колонкой:

```
 Товар:
    Апельсиновый сок
    Сок с апельсином
    /----/
```

Есть строки кода для поиска:

```
    q = request.args.get('q') # указывает к примеру url запрос q 'апельсин',
                              # где буква 'a' с маленькой буквы
    /----/
    res = Table.query.filter(Table.name.contains(q))
```

В результате получаем: сок с **апельсином**.
Как сделать так, что бы он находил все поля содержащие слово **апельсин** независимо от регистра букв. В данном случае находил и сок с апельсином, и апельсиновый сок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = Table.query.filter(Table.name.ilike('%' + q + '%'))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Сам не додумался чего-то. Ушел куда-то в сторону велосипедов. :)